# How to use the auto generated delete button in radgrid to delete a row in a radgrid databound to a datatable using DeleteCommand?

Tags: c#, telerik, radgrid, delete-row

I have the following HTML code:

```html
<telerik:RadGrid SkinID="RadGridSkin" ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="true" ShowHeader="true" RegisterWithScriptManager="false" Width="1000px" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource" ViewStateMode="Disabled" ShowGroupPanel="false"
ClientSettings-Scrolling-AllowScroll="false" GridLines="None" AllowSorting="true" AllowMultiRowSelection="false" HeaderStyle-CssClass="info-title" GroupHeaderItemStyle-CssClass="info" GroupPanel-CssClass="info" CssClass="align-left" HorizontalAlign="Center"
AutoGenerateEditColumn="true" AutoGenerateDeleteColumn="true" OnDeleteCommand="RadGrid1_DeleteCommand" OnUpdateCommand="RadGrid1_UpdateCommand">

  <ClientSettings>

    <Selecting AllowRowSelect="false" />
  </ClientSettings>

  <MasterTableView ShowHeadersWhenNoRecords="true">

    <NoRecordsTemplate>
      <div style="text-align: center;">
        <asp:Literal ID="NoData_lt" Text="<%$Resources:Strings,Nodatatodisplay %>" runat="server" />
      </div>
    </NoRecordsTemplate>

    <Columns>
      <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name" SortExpression="Name" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Strings, Name %>" HeaderButtonType="TextButton" />
      <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Email" SortExpression="Email" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Strings, Email%>" HeaderButtonType="TextButton" />
      <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Provider" SortExpression="Provider" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Strings, Provider%>" HeaderButtonType="TextButton" />
      <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Warehouse" SortExpression="Warehouse" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Strings, Warehouse%>" HeaderButtonType="TextButton" />
    </Columns>

  </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

I'm trying to write the code for the `RadGrid1_DeleteCommand` event:

```js
 protected void RadGrid1_DeleteCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e) {
   int i; //I want i to represent the index of row to be deleted
   DataRow dr = testTable.Rows[i];
   dr.Delete();
 }
```

How can I get the `index` of the `row` in which I clicked the auto generated `Delete button` and save it in my `int` variable?

Comment: Have you looked at what data GridCommandEventArgs (your `e` parameter) contains?

Comment: Canceled
CommandArgument
CommandName
CommandSource
Equals
ExecuteCommand
GetHashCode
GetType
Item
ToString

Comment: That was a hint to continue looking, not a request to tell me what's in it. I can already guess. What does the `Item` property contain? Work from there. =)

Comment: lol my bad thank you for pointing out a direction